# spark strucuted streaming write errors

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running into some odd errors when I consume and sink kafka messages. I'm running 2.3.0, and I know this was working prior in some other version.

```
val event = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <server list>)
.option("subscribe", <topic>)
.load()

val filesink_query = outputdf.writeStream
.partitionBy(<some column>)
.format("parquet")
.option("path", <some path in EMRFS>)
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/ingestcheckpoint")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
.start 



java.lang.IllegalStateException: /tmp/outputagent/_spark_metadata/0 doesn't exist when compacting batch 9 (compactInterval: 10)
```

I'm rather confused, is this an error in the newest version of spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue seemed to be related to using S3n over s3a and only having checkpoints on hdfs not s3. this is highly annoying sin e I would like to avoid hard coding dns or ips in my code.